# Display Local Scheduled Repeating Notifications on Condition

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using flutter_local_notifications plugin to schedule notifications, but I want to achieve two things.

1. The scheduled notification should run some code every time, before showing the notification to check whether or not to display the notification.
2. I want to specify a custom time interval, instead of the options given by RepeatInterval

Comment: If it only android, you can use this : https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_alarm_manager

Comment: I tried the same, and everything works fine when the app is running, but after I have explicitly closed the app, it doesn't work.

Comment: @AyushShekhar if you have found a way to display recurring notifications only when a condition is met, please share. As far as I know the only way to do it is by managing background tasks with something like [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager)...

Comment: @pierrea I didn't. The approach you mentioned is what I had to follow then and I would do the same now. Still searching for a better solution.